# Combining strings java (stringtokenizer)

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I would like to combine a string of words for eg. aero-plane
To do that , I would do a if else to check for the string "-" and if it is valid in the words it would then combine both aero and plane together to form aeroplane. I know how to do the check portion but I don't really know how to concatenate them together. I am using the java stringtokenizer api to do the following.

Comment: Did you even google this question ?

Comment: Probably didn't know what to search because it is an XY question.

Comment: From the [Javadoc for `StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html): _StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code_. Don't use `StringTokenizer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method on java strings to replace the target string (in your case a dash) with a blank string:

```
String dash = "aero-plane";
String noDash = dash.replace("-", "");
System.out.println(noDash);
```

prints `aeroplane`

There is no reason to use StringTokenizer here unless you are getting these tokens from outside of the code that you control, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: replaceAll() would be more better option to replace all occurrences

Comment: I know how to remove it but how can i join both strings together?

Comment: You don't need to join anything, replace will give you the complete string back to you.

Comment: this answer has been flagged as a low quality answer, please provide some explanation :)

Comment: Sure, added some more code and link to the javadoc of method in question.

Comment: `replaceAll` is the wrong method here, `replace` is the correct one. Using `replaceAll`, which takes **regex** input, shows a fundamental misunderstanding of the `String` API.

Comment: @BoristheSpider you are right; I had it as replace before and then doubted myself due to a previous comment to change it to replaceAll. Should have confirmed it again on my own.

Answer (score 0):

If you are tokenizing the string using StringTokenizer in this way then this might help or else provide more information to get better help

```
String str="aero-plane";
StringTokenizer tr= new StringTokenizer(str,"-");
StringBuilder br = new StringBuilder();
while(tr.hasMoreTokens()){
    String token = tr.nextToken();
    br.append(token);
}
System.out.println(br.toString());
```